# Params changing when calling a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have params with "start_date", "end_date" and "filter"

Before calling this line, params[:start_date] is, for example, "2022-02-07" and end_date is "2022-02-09". So far so good.

```
format.csv{send_data @records.to_csv(params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:filter]), filename: "fileName.csv"}
```

After calling that line, inside the method 'self.to_csv(...)', if I print the values of start_date now it is the same as end_date.

```
def self.to_csv(start_date, end_date, filter)
binding.pry # Here, I print the values of the params and they changed for some reason.
...
end
```

I tried to pass @ records, convert @ records to an array and use that, and even tried to pass params. Every single time, the argument :start_date changes.

Complete (and relevant) model and controller code:
record.rb

```
  def self.to_csv(start_date, end_date, filter)
    titles = %w(title1 title2 title3)
    attributes = %w(attr1 attr2 attr3)
    CSV.generate("\uFEFF", headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << titles
      all.each do |record|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| record.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
```

records_controller.rb

```
def index
    if params[:year].present?
      @delayed_records = Record.unscoped.delayed.not_current_year(params[:year])
      @records = Record.unscoped.getFilters(params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:filter]).not_current_year(params[:year])
    else
      @delayed_records = Record.delayed
      @records = Record.getFilters(params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:filter])
    end

    start_date = params[:start_date]
    end_date = params[:end_date]
    filter = params[:filter]

    # Everything works up until this point. Params are OK
 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @records.to_csv(start_date, end_date, filter), filename: "fileName.csv" }
    end
  end
```

To simplify this concept, imagine this situation:

```
methodA(num){
   print(num)
}
methodA(5)

// Output -> Prints 1
```

Comment: @dbugger I don't think it's relevant. I've been using that method for a few months and works fine. It just grabs every record and starts to filter the list down according to user settings.

Comment: I don't think I understand your `to_csv` method. That method accept three arguments, but I don't see where any of those arguments is used. What was your intention in passing them in?

Comment: Implementing this as a class method on the model is pretty weird and not a great idea as models in Rails already have an insane number of responsibilities. A better choice is to create a class such as serializer or service object that takes a collection of records and turns them into CSV.

Comment: The controller code is also kind of bizarre as you declare the local variables `start_date` , `end_date` and `filter` half way through the method after using `params[:start_date], params[:end_date]` twice. Whats the point of that?

Comment: I actually didn't use the variables passed as arguments. I just used them to visualize where the error was. According to what I see, when I use @records.to_csv, Rails is not passing the "array" of records, it is passing a SQL query. That query was wrong so I passed all the variables used in the query to figure out which one was causing an error.